# A quick method to map a data type string to the corresponding type?

Tags: string, type-conversion, dolphindb

I want to create a table and then append the data from a CSV file to it. Before that, I need to define the table schema. However, the data types obtained from the `extractSchema` are in STRING format, which cannot be directly used for initializing a table schema.

The only solution I know is to use a dictionary to map the strings to their corresponding types, such as data_type_dict[`STRING] = STRING. Can anyone share a more efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `parseExpr` function. Refer to the following script:

```
s = extractTextSchema("/hdd/data/finance/2021tick/20211130tick.csv")
t = table(10:0, s.name, each(x->parseExpr(x).eval(), s.type))
schema(t)
```

// output

```
chunkPath->
partitionColumnIndex->-1
colDefs->
name        typeString typeInt extra comment
----------- ---------- ------- ----- -------
SecurityID  INT        4                    
TradeTime   TIMESTAMP  12                   
TradePrice  DOUBLE     16                   
TradeQty    INT        4                    
TradeAmount DOUBLE     16                   
BuyNo       INT        4                    
SellNo      INT        4                    
TradeIndex  INT        4                    
ChannelNo   INT        4                    
TradeBSFlag CHAR       2                    
BizIndex    INT        4
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use string for table schema definition, like official doc demonstrated:

```
table(100:5, `name`id`value, `STRING`INT`DOUBLE);
```